# autocomplete: how do I avoid a duplicate search?

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

I use JQuery plugin [autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) as a kind of dataset chooser.  If the user chooses a value from the autocomplete lookup, the database is queried for the matching dataset.  If the user types in a new value, the user can enter a new dataset. An issue arises when the user types in an existing value rather than choosing it from the autocomplete lookup. When this is done, the autocomplete `.result()` method is not called and no dataset is retrieved.  To fix this I added a `.blur(function(){$(this).search();});` to the input element.  This fixed the original problem.

Now I have the problem that `.result()` fires on selection from lookup AND on blur. I would like `.result()` to fire on selection from lookup OR on blur. How do I make that happen?

Here is my code:

```
$('#groupset').autocomplete('ajax/php/leeruns.php');
$('#groupset').result(
    function(event, data, formatted) {
        if(data){
            $('#groupsetdesc').val(formatted);
            groups.load(data[1]); //retrieve matching dataset
        } else {
            $('#groupsetdesc').val('');
        }
    }
).blur(function(){$(this).search();});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the current value of data in a persistent variable called previous and not load the dataset if it is the same.

```
var loaded_previous;
$('#groupset').autocomplete('ajax/php/leeruns.php');
$('#groupset').result(
function(event, data, formatted) {
    if(data && data[1] != loaded_previous){
        loaded_previous = data[1];
        $('#groupsetdesc').val(formatted);
        groups.load(data[1]); //retrieve matching dataset
    } else {
        $('#groupsetdesc').val('');
    }
}
).blur(function(){$(this).search();});
```